# How to set a row of white pixels to a row of red, a row of green, and a row of blue on the iPhone X

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es, metal

I am developing the pixel display function of iPhone X mobile phone. I want to realize that a single line of white only contains one line of red, one line of green, and one line of blue, but I use the following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {
      if (i == 500 ){
         data[(i*width + j)*4] = (Byte) (255) ;
         data[(i*width + j)*4+1] = (Byte) (255) ;     
         data[(i*width + j)*4+2] = (Byte) (255) ;  
         data[(i*width + j)*4+3] = (Byte)255;
      }else{
         data[(i*width + j)*4] = (Byte) (0) ;
         data[(i*width + j)*4+1] = (Byte) (0) ;     
         data[(i*width + j)*4+2] = (Byte) (0) ;  
         data[(i*width + j)*4+3] = (Byte)255;
      }
    }
 }
```

When only one line of white is displayed, it actually contains two lines of red, one line of green, and two lines of blue. The effect of shooting with a microscope is shown on the left of the picture, and my desired effect is on the right of the picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPUss.jpg

Comment: But that will no longer be white, will it? Do you know / understand what sub pixels a single pixel is actually composed of?

Comment: I don't care white, I only want to display  one line of red, one line of green, and one line of blue. Also I don't know sub pixels. So can you tell me how to develop this function?

Comment: Then read up on it, read up on the used displays, the technology e.g. LED vs OLED, sub pixels, etc. Either you care about pixels on this level - then do some deep research on it or do not care about the pixels, you cannot have it both ways by caring about it but not understanding it.

Comment: as long you write into an image buffer that is displayed with given display driver, you are not directly dealing with LED/OLED at all. You try to solve a problem that is hardware with the intend to change that by software. which will never work

Comment: Thank you very much,I will try to find other solution. @OI Sen